# Avidemux, play only selection?

Tags: video, video-editing, avidemux

I am trying to use [**Avidemux**](http://avidemux.org) to create a clip from a larger video.

I can select position `A` and position `B`, but I do not see a way to simply play **only what I have selected**.

To answer a question

> How are you creating a clip?

With Avidemux you select points `A` and `B`, then choose the option to create a clip from those points. The Issue at hand is playing back only the selected portion **beforehand** in order to make sure it is correct.

Comment: How are you *creating* a clip? You have to save it to clip the video. I take it you mean you want to *play* a clip? What is the point to that? Can you not simply mark the start and end of the clip, then save it to a new file (using *Copy* for the A/V modes) and just play it with a normal video-player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `ffplay` to work better.

```
ffplay -autoexit -i test.mkv -ss 20 -t 4.024
```

Comment: Is this really a "solution" for the problem?  Instead of being able to fine-tune what you want by selecting, you're now having to "do the math" to get the same thing.

Comment: I ask because the initial question was about avidemux, and the answer has nothing to do with it.  I appreciate that you you found a solution to your problem.  But, for just a moment, consider that some other person were trying to do with avidemux what you were trying to do, found this question, and then found the answer you used, which for them could be completely unsuitable.

Comment: At this point it seems the simple fact is that it cannot be done, so instead of pulling the question i put what works for me. If a good enough answer pops up then mine will fade to the bottom, as is the design and intention of this site.

Answer (score 0):

There is no play-only-selected option (though you could probably write a JavaScript or Python script), but you can use the *Go to Marker A* command (<kbd>Page Up</kbd>), followed by *Play* (<kbd>Space</kbd>). You can also click the buttons under *Selection* to jump to the marked points in the video.